# Count the number of features in a given map extent as dynamic text in map layout

Tags: qgis, expression, atlas, feature-count

In QGIS (3.22) print layout I want to calculate the number of companies in a given map extent as a dynamic text via expression. I am using the Atlas Tool.

However, with the following code I do not get further. The calculated number is always "0".

```
aggregate( 
'firms',
'count',
intersects($geometry,map_get(item_variables('map1'),'map_extent')))
```

What's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `intersect` function as the `expression` parameter, rather than the `filter`.

This expression works for me:

```
aggregate( 
    layer:='firms',
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:=$id,
    filter:=intersects(
                $geometry,
                map_get(item_variables('Map 1'), 'map_extent')    -- ensure the name of the map is correct
            )
)
```

Ensure also that your map extent and the layer are the same CRS (or transform one to the other in the expression, using the `transform` function).